# GETH + web3.js Max Transaction Fee

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

There is a built-in default max transaction fee of 1 ETH with my GETH node + web3.js library.  Where can I change that?  I cannot find the option anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're connecting over RPC, you're limited to 1 ETH by default unless you include this flag when you start geth:

`--rpc.txfeecap value`  where `value` is the amount in *ether*.

[*Reference:* https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options]

Comment: Thanks.  I'm assuming the transaction fee is calculated with the gas limit and not the actual gas ?

Comment: That's correct : your local node can only estimate the cost of the transaction based on the state of the chain it sees. The actual gas could end up being different if the state changes before your transaction gets mined.